# NextJs api routes, 2 POST requests how to differentiate

Tags: next.js

I have a question, I am making an app in NextJS and I have a problem. On one page I can buy, sell and delete the asset. How to differentiate buy and sell if both are POST requests in API Route. What to do, should I add some 'type'? Or Is there a better way?

```
const handler = async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  if (req.method === "POST") {
   assetIdForBuy = req.body
  }

  if (req.method === "POST") {
    const assetIdForSell = req.body;
  }
};

export default handler;
```

Comment: It depends. Is the request body any different between each request? It's really up to you how you'd want to differentiate them. You could even use different API routes for each of them.

Answer (score 1):

well, you can simply add some type check like,

```
if(req.body.data.type === "delete"){ // or something like that whatever fits.
    assetIdForDelete = req.body
{
```

Answer (score 0):

actually you are making a request at a single url for both buy and sell but then you are separating them on the bases of method of request so i will not recommend this for example you are sending request at http://localhost:3000/assets and then you are diving the request on the basis of request type that you are sending instead of use 2 different routes for both for example:

For Buying of Assets it will be
localhost:3000/api/assets/buy

and for selling of assets it will be
localhost:3000/api/assets/sell